# Python split in for-loop with multiple pairs (name:value) of output

Tags: python

I have the following code in python:

```
features = {}
    for string in vector:
        string = 'name1:value1 name2:value2 name3:value3'
        name,value = string.split(":");
        features[self._getFeatureId(name)] = float(value);
    return features
```

But when I run the code, it gives the following error:

```
name,value = string.split(":");
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This is suppose to be a for-loop which is suppose to split them into 3 different pairs of name and values. What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: There are more than two strings in the resultant list. You should just use `values = string.split(":")` and you will get a list that will work regardless of how many strings there are. You probably first want to split on space first, then split those strings on colon, to get the name/value pairs. Try `[s.split(':') for s in string.split()]` to get it in the format you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
string = "name1:value1 name2:value2 name3:value3"
split_on_colon = string.split(":");  # output = ['name1', 'value1 name2', 'value2 name3', 'value3']
split_on_space = string.split(); # No argument means split on white space; output = ['name1:value1', 'name2:value2', 'name3:value3']
# The split you desire is on space and THEN split each item on colon
desired_split = [s.split(':') for s in string.split()] # output = [['name1', 'value1'], ['name2', 'value2'], ['name3', 'value3']]
```

Also, the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` couldn't be clearer. It literally says that you are trying to unpack lesser values than there are in the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I have also managed to get it to work with the following code, by splitting it with " " first, then for each name value pair, split it with ":"

```
features = {}
    for string in vector:
        string = name1:value1 name2:value2 name3:value3
        valueTemp = string.split(" ");
        for string2 in valueTemp:
            name,value = string2.split(":");
            features[self._getFeatureId(name)] = float(value);
    return features
```